# Event received in Parent component is undefined

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, event

I have a `Parent` and a `child` component. I am trying to dispatch an event from child and capture it in parent component. However I get the event as '`undefined`' in parent. What am I doing wrong here?

Parent HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <lightning-card title="Sample App">
                <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                    <c-child onsearch={searchItem}></c-child>
                </p>
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Parent JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    itemId = '';

    searchItem(event) { 
        console.log('Event received => ' + console.log(event));
        this.itemId = (event && event.detail && event.detail.eventItemId) || '';
        console.log('itemId received => ' + console.log(this.itemId));
    }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item class="slds-align-middle slds-text-align_left">
            <lightning-combobox class="slds-align-middle slds-text-align_left" name="" value={selectedOptionId}
                options={options} onchange={handleChange}>
            </lightning-combobox>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Child JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    selectedOptionId='';
    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
        ];
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.selectedOptionId = event.detail.value;
        console.log('handleChange option selected ===> ' + this.selectedOptionId);
        const searchEvent = new CustomEvent('search', {
            detail: {
                eventItemId: this.selectedOptionId
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(searchEvent);
    }
}
```

In console log I see:

[image]

Comment: This could mean your payload is not getting delivered have you tried isolating the issue by sending simple data? For example just send detail:'dummyText'? Also just out of curiosity I'm not sure why you are adding a console within a console?

Comment: I used this -         `const searchEvent = new CustomEvent('search', {
            detail: {
                eventItemId: 'dummyText'
            }
        });` However I see the same result. Is that what you were thinking to try?

Comment: Your logging is wrong. Try ```console.log("event received => ", event);```

Comment: No just `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('search', { detail: 'dummyText' }));`

Comment: Ah that was the mistake. I was using double console.log. Thanks for pointing it out. I could select that as answer if you wish to add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to incorrect use of console.log() I was getting the values as undefined.

Incorrect usage:

```
console.log('Event received => ' + console.log(event));
this.itemId = (event && event.detail && event.detail.eventItemId) || '';
console.log('itemId received => ' + console.log(this.itemId));
```

Please check the comments sections for more details.